# Browser notification text change

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, cross-browser

I would like to change notifications send by browser.
For example if I write email address without "@" sign I will get notification:

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox

[image]

Is there a way to change notification text and write the same text for all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your custom message here')` to set a custom message of your choice.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08ujt04s/

Comment: That's it. Thank you for quck response.